# Compiling application using new DLL but running using old DLL

Tags: c#, dll, dynamic-linking

I have an application that uses(does not implement) an interface in a separate DLL. I recently mades changes to this interface. My application, however, does not use any of the new features in this interface.

My question is: Is it ok to run the application using the old DLL if I have compiled the application using the new DLL( with the new changes).

Comment: "Is it OK" really depends on what your requirements are.  If it works for your application and you don't want to change it, you don't have to, but it's usually better to reference the project rather than the dll to make sure you don't run into a dependency issue later on.

Comment: I am actually referencing the project that is why i am compiling against the new code. But when i deploy it, the old DLL of the library is still out there. I just want to know if i need to deploy the new DLL also.

Comment: @Alvin Yes. Either copy the updated reference to the bin directory of the project that uses it, or rebuild the dependent project and it should find the updated version (assuming the reference is added from the original build location and `CopyLocal` is true.

Comment: @M.Babcock So I can not compile using the new code and run using the old code eventhough my application doesn't use the new methods in the interface? I think I don't quite understand how linking works in .net

Comment: @Alvin - No, that is an option (it was the first option presented in my previous comment). It only works if the Assembly version didn't change and it isn't strongly named. You'll have to copy the assembly over manually though.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine under the right circumstances.

I had to try this out to be sure...but, in fact it does seem to work out alright.  I created an interface in a dll, referenced it in an application and used reflection to check the methods on the interface in the dll.  Then, modified the interface, recompiled both the dll and the application, and the application is able to retrieve the methods on the interface of either the old, or the new dll.

Comment: It seems to work fine for me too. I am just worried that the app will throw some runtime exception later.

Comment: Well, if it isn't throwing one now...It's just ones and zeros, why would it throw one later?

Comment: check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=VS.100%29.aspx